# State of a persistent object in a Hibernate session

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, persistent, hibernate-session

I've got a probably embarrassingly easy question regarding Hibernate:

When I've got a persisted instance of an object, and some of these object's properties are modified inside the same [`Session`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html), are those changes visible for me too?

Or do I have to [`refresh`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#refresh%28java.lang.Object%29) the object in order to get it's current state?

---

I'd like to extend my question: What if these changes are not made inside the same `Session`? What if they are made in a `Session`, provided by the same [`SessionFactory`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an entity loaded two or more times (doesn't matter if with `Query.list()` or `Session.load()`) then always you get the same instance of the Java object. And as it is the same instance, each modification of this instance is visible wherever you use this instance, and so this also is the case for modifications which are not persisted to the database (which is a certain danger).

If the entity is loaded two times using two different sessions (it doesn't matter if the sessions are from the same SessionFactory or not), then you get two instances of the Java class. These two instances are independent. One instance does not get informed about modifications in the other instance. This also is not the case if the modification is persisted into the database. Even if you load again the entity and it is already in the session cache, you do not get the modification (Example: `session1.load(entity); session2.save(entity); session1.load(entity);` then `session1` does not load the changes which   `session2`did, because the entity already was in the cache). The same is the case if a modification is done directly with SQL outside your program. To load the modification you either have to `evict()` the instance or use a new session. In this case it is recommendable to have a versioned column (a column mapped with the `<version>` clause) to avoid losses of modifications.

Comment: Another corner case is [`merge`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge%28T%29): you can have a persistent instance, and a non-persistent (or detached?) instance with the same identity, and when you call `merge` with the latter, any changes in it will become visible in the former. However, the non-persistance instance does not itself persistent, so it will not show any future changes. The normal use is to throw that instance away after the merge and use the persistent instance instead.

Answer (score 0):

No refresh needed, it will be visible unless it is detached.